# QStackedLayout equivalent in WPF

Tags: wpf, qt

I'm a quite experienced Qt programmer and I used QStackedLayout a lot to show different widgets in the main window. Can someone please point me to an equivalent construct in WPF: Is there such a thing like QStackedLayout? If not, how is this pattern used in WPF?

Basically I have a WPF Ribbon Application and if the Ribbon Group is switched the corresponding "widget" / XAML should be displayed in the remaining area ("content").

Thanks, dude.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a native panel or control that would do that, but you could leverage the TabControl to accomplish it. You'd need to use a custom Style, though like so:

```
<Style x:Key="NoTabsTabControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                        KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      ContentSource="SelectedContent"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" 
                             Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" 
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then use it like:

```
<TabControl Style="{StaticResource NoTabsTabControlStyle}">
    <TabItem Content="One" />
    <TabItem Content="Two" />
</TabControl>
```

Then to display one set of content, you'd set SelectedIndex on the TabControl.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late for topic starter but may be of some help to people who comes here searching for WPF version of QStackedLayout, like me.

I used the very simplified implementation of WPF layout example, throwing out virtually all things layout. 
The component is based on StackLayout to allow for simple visual design, in design time it just behaves like normal stack panel.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace org.tequilacat.stacklayout {

    /// <summary>
    /// QStackedLayout implementation for WPF
    /// only one child is displayed extended to the panel size.
    /// In design time it behaves like stack panel
    /// </summary>
    public class StackLayoutPanel : StackPanel {

        private bool isDesignTime() {
            return System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this);
        }

        private bool useBaseBehaviour() {
            return isDesignTime();
        }

        // in runtime just return the given arg
        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize) {
            if (useBaseBehaviour()) {
                return base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
            }

            return availableSize;
        }

        // in runtime arrange all children to the given arg
        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize) {
            if (useBaseBehaviour()) {
                return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
            }

            foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren) {
                child.Arrange(new Rect(finalSize));
            }

            return finalSize;
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML is

```
<Window ... xmlns:uilib="clr-namespace:org.tequilacat.stacklayout">

  <uilib:StackLayoutPanel >
    <StackPanel Name="projectPropertyPanel"> ... </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Name="configurationPanel"> ... </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Name="casePanel"> ... </StackPanel>
  </uilib:StackLayoutPanel>
```

In Run time the visible component is chosen via Visibility property (here depends on my business logic, uiState can take 3 values activating one of panels). It's very basic, one can implement own CurrentPage property or so, I just kept it simple:

```
projectPropertyPanel.Visibility = (uiState == UiState.ProjectProperties) ? 
  Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
configurationPanel.Visibility = (uiState == UiState.ConfigurationSelected) ? 
  Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
casePanel.Visibility = (uiState == UiState.CaseSelected) ? 
  Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Comment: After 3 years of c#-ping I found that the best equivalent of QStackedLayout is Grid where all children are added to default column and row, which is 0. They share the same bounds and topmost is visible. When I need to display one of them I set its visibility in codebehind to displayed and others visibility to hidden.